# How can I prevent Flash scaling up movieclips inside my DataGrid Cell?

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, movieclip, cellrenderer, flash-cs6

I have an AS3 DataGrid component, in one column I use a custom Cell Renderer to load a movie clip from the library. However the movieclip seems to scale to fit the height of the cell ( if I change the datagrid cell height property, the movie clip will scale to fit). I want to keep the movieclip size as I have set it in the library rather than scaling to fit the size of the cell. How can I do this?

many thanks